# How to use Haskell's readFile function for multiple files

Tags: haskell, io

I understand a little bit about IO. I understand that you can use `readFile` to get the content of a file. For example like this:

```
main = do
    let inputFilePath = "C:\\Haskell\\myawesomeprogram\\files\\a.txt"
    content <- readFile inputFilePath
    print content
```

Calling the program:

```
> runghc myawesomeprogram
"AAA"
```

Awesome, that works! Now I want to read the content from multiple files.
I tried something like this:

```
files = ["C:\\Haskell\\myawesomeprogram\\files\\a.txt", "C:\\Haskell\\myawesomeprogram\\files\\b.txt","C:\\Haskell\\myawesomeprogram\\files\\c.txt"]


main :: IO ()
main = do
    filesContent <- readFiles files
    print filesContent

readFiles (x:xs) = do 
    content <- readFile x
    content : readFiles xs
```

This will give me the following error message:

```
myawesomeprogram.hs:6:21: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
      Expected type: IO String
        Actual type: [String]
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: filesContent <- readFiles files
      In the expression:
        do filesContent <- readFiles files
           print filesContent
      In an equation for `main':
          main
            = do filesContent <- readFiles files
                 print filesContent
  |
6 |     filesContent <- readFiles files
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

myawesomeprogram.hs:9:1: error:
    Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
    Expected type: [FilePath] -> [String]
      Actual type: [FilePath] -> IO String
  |
9 | readFiles (x:xs) = do
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

myawesomeprogram.hs:11:5: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
      Expected type: IO String
        Actual type: [String]
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: content : readFiles xs
      In the expression:
        do content <- readFile x
           content : readFiles xs
      In an equation for `readFiles':
          readFiles (x : xs)
            = do content <- readFile x
                 content : readFiles xs
   |
11 |     content : readFiles xs
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm doing something wrong, however, I can't see a way to do it right.
Can you do it the right way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`readFiles xs` is not a list, so you can't prepend an item to it. Instead, it's an *action*, which, when executed, would produce a list.

More specifically, the type of `readFiles xs` is `IO [String]` (`IO` is the type of executable actions), whereas a list would have type `[String]`. This is what the error message is telling you: cannot match type `IO [String]` with `[String]`.

So to get the list, you have to execute the action, just like you're executing `readFile`

```
readFiles (x:xs) = do
    content <- readFile x
    theRest <- readFiles xs
    pure (content : theRest)
```

Also note that `readFiles` doesn't know what to do when its argument is an empty list. You should get a warning about it at compile time, and if you don't fix it, you'll get a crash at runtime.

To fix, just add an equation for the empty list case:

```
readFiles [] = pure []
readFiles (x:xs) = do
    content <- readFile x
    theRest <- readFiles xs
    pure (content : theRest)
```

Comment: Jeez, that's simple. Defining `<-` twice in `readFiles` solved it! 
This makes me wonder, why was I not able to solve that by myself? I guess it has to do with thinking in Haskell while being fluent in mainstream programming languages. By the way, I tried to use `return` instead of `pure`, and that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something to every item in a list, you use `map`.

However, `map readFile files` over a list only gives you a list of actions that will produce their contents, rather than a list of their contents. There is then `sequence` which will take a list of actions, and turn it into an action that produces a list of their results. Mapping an action and sequencing it is a frequent enough concern that this is shortened to `mapM`. It is located in `Control.Monad`.

The code you want is thus:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    filesContent <- mapM readFile files
    print filesContent
```

Please do not roll your own function to do this.